# Multi-filtering element by checkbox groups

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to create a simple filter UI using this code but I have two issues here.

1- Filters by Color is not working if you start with them. They work if the user first filters by Shape

2- on Filter by Shape if you select `square` it will filter the boxes correctly but if you unchecked the  `square` it will remove all boxes (which is not correct it should display all boxes now)

What am I doing wrong and how I can fix this?

```js
var checks = $('.shape,.color,.size'),
  boxes = $('.box')
checks.on('change', function() {
  var selector = checks.map(function(i) {
    var name = this.className,
      checked = $(":checked", this)
    if (checked.length === 0) checked = $(this).children()
    return checked.map(function() {
      return "[data-" + name + "='" + $(this).data(name) + "']"
    }).get().join(",")
  }).get()
  //console.log(selector)
  var okBoxes = boxes
  selector.forEach(function(sel) {
    okBoxes = okBoxes.filter(sel)
  })
   // animate to left
   
    okBoxes.show(500);
  boxes.not(okBoxes).hide(500)
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:40px;
}
.box{
float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
.red{
  background:red;
}
.green{
  background:green;}
.yellow{
  background:yellow;}
.diamond {

  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  transform:rotate(45deg) !important;
 width:60px;
}
.circle {

  height: 60px;
border-radius:50%;
 width:60px;
}
.square{
    height: 60px;
 width:60px;
}
.size input{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Filter By Shape
<hr />
<div class="shape">
   <div class="list-group">
        <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="square">square
  <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="circle">circle
  <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="diamond">diamond
   </div>

</div>
<hr />
<br />
Filter By Color
<hr />
<div class="color">
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="red">Red
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="yellow">yellow
  <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="green">green
</div>
<br />
<div class="row map">
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red square" data-shape="square" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow square" data-shape="square" data-color="yellow" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="yellow" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="52">52</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow square" data-shape="square" data-color="yellow" data-size="54">54</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="54">54</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red square" data-shape="square" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="52">52</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="53">53</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="54">54</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="52">52</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The script is not going to work if you add additional classes on your filter groups and if you change you html structure with just tiny bit will brake too.

Here is your working example, but I won't suggest using it for long run.

```js
var checks = $('.shape,.color,.size'),
  boxes = $('.box')
checks.on('change', function() {
  
  
  var selector = checks.map(function(i) {
    var name = this.className,
      checked = $(":checked", this)
    if (checked.length === 0) checked = $(this).children()
    return checked.map(function() {
      return "[data-" + name + "='" + $(this).data(name) + "']"
    }).get().join(",")
  }).get()
  //console.log(selector)
  var okBoxes = boxes
  selector.forEach(function(sel) {
    okBoxes = okBoxes.filter(sel)
  })
   // animate to left
   
    okBoxes.show(500);
  boxes.not(okBoxes).hide(500)
});
```

```css
body{
  padding:40px;
}
.box{
float:left;
  margin:10px;
}
.red{
  background:red;
}
.green{
  background:green;}
.yellow{
  background:yellow;}
.diamond {

  height: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  transform:rotate(45deg) !important;
 width:60px;
}
.circle {

  height: 60px;
border-radius:50%;
 width:60px;
}
.square{
    height: 60px;
 width:60px;
}
.size input{
   display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="filters">
    Filter By Shape
    <hr />
    <div class="shape" data-group="shape">
        <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="square">square
        <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="circle">circle
        <input type="checkbox" name="shape" data-shape="diamond">diamond
    </div>

    <hr />
    <br />
    Filter By Color
    <hr />
    <div class="color" data-group="color">
        <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="red">Red
        <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="yellow">yellow
        <input type="checkbox" name="color" data-color="green">green
    </div>
</div>
<br />
<div class="row map">
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red square" data-shape="square" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow square" data-shape="square" data-color="yellow" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="yellow" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="52">52</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow square" data-shape="square" data-color="yellow" data-size="54">54</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="54">54</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red square" data-shape="square" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="52">52</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="red" data-size="53">53</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="54">54</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box red circle" data-shape="circle" data-color="red" data-size="50">50</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box green square" data-shape="square" data-color="green" data-size="51">51</div>
  <div class="col-md-2 animated box yellow diamond" data-shape="diamond" data-color="yellow" data-size="52">52</div>
</div>
```